# How to get client information in fluid framework?

Tags: javascript, fluid-framework

Can I get information specific to which client has joined the session? For e.g If I want to add a new div to the DOM element with the id of the client whenever a new client joins the session and loads a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen on the audience object for new client who have joined/left the session.
[Fluid Framework Audience Docs](https://fluidframework.com/docs/build/audience/)
[Fluid Framework Audience Events](https://fluidframework.com/docs/apis/fluid-framework/iserviceaudienceevents/)

```js
const { container, services } =
    await client.getContainer(...);
const audience = services.audience;
audience.on("memberAdded", (clientId: string, member: AzureClient) => {
  // new member has been added
}
```

Comment: Thank @Skyler for helping me out.